# Set confidenceScore threshold for Custom Question Answering in Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the [CQA package](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-components/tree/main/packages/Recognizers/CustomQuestionAnswering/dotnet) for my bot built in Composer but can't figure out how I can set the confidenceScore threshold. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I'm slightly unclear. The confidence score should be generated by the CQA service. Are you referring to a threshold?

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant the threshold!

Comment: @AP01 do you know how to set the threshold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the confidenceScore threshold, you have to add the threshold property to the JSON config in the custom recognizer configuration window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The **confidenceScoreThreshold** is provided by Language Services.
To configure the value of confidenceScoreThreshold, search for **QnAMakerBaseDialog.cs** in the bot source code files.

In **QnAMakerBaseDialog.cs,** search for **QnAMakerOptions**
[image]

```
return Task.FromResult(new QnAMakerOptions  
{ScoreThreshold = _scoreThreshold,  
Top = _topAnswers,  
QnAId = 0,  
RankerType = _rankerType,  
IsTest = _isTest,  
EnablePreciseAnswer = _enablePreciseAnswer,  
IncludeUnstructuredSources = _includeUnstructuredSources,  
Filters = { }  
});
```

Here you can adjust the threshold score by changing the **_scoreThreshold** to your value.

Comment: Hi! You are talking about the QnAMaker dialog and not the [CQA dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-components/tree/main/packages/Recognizers/CustomQuestionAnswering/dotnet). This is not available like this for CQA.

Answer (score 0):

The `CustomQuestionAnsweringRecognizer.cs` object has a [Threshold property](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-components/blob/bec77d8c5d0974cccc05fcd2af2f6b1fdcba1ce0/packages/Recognizers/CustomQuestionAnswering/dotnet/QuestionAnswering/CustomQuestionAnsweringRecognizer.cs#L97) that you can set:

```cs
public NumberExpression Threshold { get; set; } = 0.3F;
```

As you can see, it defaults to 0.3 if not explicitly set.